# Remove a published package

Tags: python, python-poetry

To publish a python package to pypi from poetry one use :

`poetry publish`

Whats the command to remove a published package ?

Comment: AFAIK you'll have to do that manually

Comment: It depends on the artifactory used. If you are using `jfrog`, please refer to the API to delete the package remotely https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem